# C++ : assign values to data members of an object within a class

Tags: c++, class, object, struct, member

I am trying to make a fight sequence. Right now I am just prototyping.

What I would like to do is define a function for the fight sequence in a class, and initialize different monsters to fight with. I have created a data structure in the .h file with the name 'monster'. I then initialize the monster tiger within the class. But when I go into my cpp to give its sound and picture, I run into errors.

What I ultimately want to do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CombatSeq.h"
int main() {

    // Initiate Combat with a Tiger.

    CombatSeq c;
    c.fight(c.tiger); 
}
```

Here is my code :

The .h file :

```
#ifndef SOURCE2_COMBATSEQ_H_
#define SOURCE2_COMBATSEQ_H_

#include <iostream>

struct monster {
    std::string sound;
    std::string picture;
};

class CombatSeq {
public:
    void fight(monster t);

    monster tiger;

private:

};
#endif /* SOURCE2_COMBATSEQ_H_ */
```

The cpp file :

```
#include "CombatSeq.h"
#include <iostream>


void CombatSeq::fight (monster t) {
    std::cout << t.picture;
    std::cout << t.sound;


}

// What would I put here to give tiger.sound & tiger.picture values?
// I have tried:

monster CombatSeq::tiger;
CombatSeq::tiger.sound = "tiger.ogg";

// But to no avail.
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.  Constructor might be a good choice.  This will get you where you're trying to go, though....

```
int main() {

// Initiate Combat with a Tiger.

CombatSeq c;
c.tiger.sound = "tiger.ogg";
c.tiger.picture = "tiger.jpg";
c.fight(c.tiger); 
}
```

That said, CombatSeq having a member of type monster makes very little sense to me.  It's hard to recommend a better way to do it without more information.

Comment: The reason I would like tiger within CombatSeq (or a different class) is simply to be organized. I would like all of my monsters loaded into one place so they can be used in different classes. Could I perhaps make a new class with all of my monsters?

Comment: One reasonable option is to make them all static members of the class.  As you have it now, every instance of CombatSeq will have it's own copies of tiger.  This, of course, has it's own syntax and it's own set of issues, which I'll leave it to you to weigh against other options.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I suppose the best way to phrase it is : Why can I initialize a new object of monster (monster tiger), but cannot assign values to its members (tiger.picture, tiger.sound, etc.)?

Comment: You cant initialize a new object of monster.  That line of code doesn't do what you think it does.  Does it even compile?

Comment: It does compile. What does it do if it doesn't make monster tiger?

Comment: It does not compile on my system (g++).  That would be the correct syntax for instantiating a static member of CombatSeq, but you've not declared it static
g++ -o obj/combatSeq.o -c src/combatSeq.cpp  --std=c++11 -Iinc
src/combatSeq.cpp:15:20: error: ‘monster CombatSeq::tiger’ is not a static data member of ‘class CombatSeq’
 monster CombatSeq::tiger;
                    ^
src/combatSeq.cpp:16:12: error: ‘tiger’ in ‘class CombatSeq’ does not name a type
 CombatSeq::tiger.sound = "tiger.ogg";
            ^
make: *** [obj/combatSeq.o] Error 1

Comment: Ok - thanks for your help. I'm sure I can figure this out :)